# How to group query results in the same row?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    Employee,
    Departmentname,
    [Week],
    Activity,
    Monday    = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'MONDAY'    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
    Tuesday   = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'TUESDAY'   THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
    Wednesday = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'WEDNESDAY' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
    Thursday  = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'THURSDAY'  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
    Friday    = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'FRIDAY'    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
    Saturday  = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'SATURDAY'  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
    substring(cast(convert(Time, dateadd(millisecond, sum(datediff(millisecond, 0, cast([Time] as datetime))), 0), 108) as VARCHAR(5)),0,9) AS 'TotalHRW'
FROM
    TimeSheet
WHERE
    [Week] LIKE 18
    AND
    Departmentname LIKE 'Returns'
    AND
    Employee LIKE 'Hand Batis'
GROUP BY
    Activity,
    WorkDate,
    Employee,
    Departmentname, 
    [Week],
    Time
ORDER BY
    Week,
    Employee
```

That produces the following result:

[image]

Now, my question is, how can I modify this query to output all the activity results in the same row? For example, instead of displaying a new row for each time on a given day, I would like to just have a single activity name and all the times in the same row entered on each particular day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it as a subquery inside a query that groups-by the same fields except `WorkDate` and gets non-NULL values for each weekday:

```
SELECT
    Employee,
    DepartmentName,
    Week,
    Activity,
    MIN( Monday ) AS Monday,
    MIN( Tuesday ) AS Tuesday ,
    MIN( Wednesday ) AS Wednesday ,
    MIN( Thursday ) AS Thursday ,
    MIN( Friday ) AS Friday ,
    MIN( Saturday ) AS Saturday
FROM
(
    -- original query here:
    SELECT
        Employee,
        Departmentname,
        [Week],
        Activity,
        Monday    = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'MONDAY'    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
        Tuesday   = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'TUESDAY'   THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
        Wednesday = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'WEDNESDAY' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
        Thursday  = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'THURSDAY'  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
        Friday    = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'FRIDAY'    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
        Saturday  = (Select CASE WHEN datename(dw, WorkDate) = 'SATURDAY'  THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TIME, 108) END),
        substring(cast(convert(Time, dateadd(millisecond, sum(datediff(millisecond, 0, cast([Time] as datetime))), 0), 108) as VARCHAR(5)),0,9) AS 'TotalHRW'
    FROM
        TimeSheet
    WHERE
        [Week] LIKE 18
        AND
        Departmentname LIKE 'Returns'
        AND
        Employee LIKE 'Hand Batis'
    GROUP BY
        Activity,
        WorkDate,
        Employee,
        Departmentname, 
        [Week],
        Time
    ORDER BY
        Week,
        Employee
) AS originalQuery
GROUP BY
    Employee,
    DepartmentName,
    Week,
    Activity
```

...though you lose the `TotalHRW` column.

An alternative approach might be to do an `UNPIVOT` from the original table data, but you haven't posted your table schema.